# How do I tell Amazon SES their IP addresses are blacklisted?

Tags: blacklist, amazon-ses

Is there an official way to tell Amazon SES about blacklisting, and ask them to talk to the other company involved?

I have had emails disappear this week and last week (Ironport doesn't even send proper bounces back to to my SNS endpoint) and discovered through https://mxtoolbox.com that Amazon's IP 54.240.3.26 is blacklisted by SORBS and Suomispam at the moment.

How do I inform Amazon of this? The documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/blacklists.html doesn't mention the process:
*We don't monitor blacklists that are unlikely to impact delivery across the entire Amazon SES service, or that don't have a measurable impact on delivery to major email providers. The blacklists offered by SORBS fall into this category. When one of our IP addresses appears on a blacklist in this category, we'll ask the provider to remove our IP addresses on a case-by-case basis.*

Comment: In translation: "We don't care, but if you use a blacklisted IP contact us and we'll request de-listing." 'Great' customer care, like many others. It's faster for yourself to perform the de-listing request if possible (blacklist owner does not request proof of ownership).

Answer (score 3):

You can open a support case with Amazon by logging into the AWS console, clicking **Support** in the upper right corner, and choosing **Support Center**, or by going to this URL: https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases#/

From there, click the **Create Case** button to open a support ticket. But you need to have realistic expectations.

It's not really realistic to expect Amazon to request delisting every time one of their addresses gets blacklisted. They have lots of IP addresses, some of which are always on blacklists, and if they do nothing, the listings eventually disappear. It's not really in their interests, or in yours, to pursue this aggressively because of how modern blocklists work.

Nowadays most blocklists like [SORBS use automation](http://www.sorbs.net/delisting/overview.shtml) rather than manual listing. Generally, an address gets automatically added to a list because it is detected sending spam, and the listings expire after a period of time. So if no more spam is sent, eventually the block simply goes away. Usually only extreme cases result in permanent listings.

Since delisting happens automatically, someone who accidentally sends spam, or who is falsely reported, usually will be affected only temporarily. Someone who keeps it up will stay on the list as long as they continue.

It is possible to request delisting, but there is a caveat: if you request delisting, and your address is then found spamming a second time, you may be penalized with a longer listing period, or even a permanent block.

In other words, unless you're absolutely sure nobody else is sending spam from your address, asking to be removed can end up hurting you instead of helping you.

Unless you're [paying Amazon for a dedicated email sending IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dedicated-ips.html), you are not the only person using that address to send email. That means you could get it delisted, and then someone else could spam from it again, relisting it, and you could be penalized.

If you ARE paying Amazon for a dedicated IP, then you're responsible for managing the address reputation yourself, since any blacklisting happens as a result of your own email sending practices.